# Uncaught Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setParams')] salesforce Aura

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc, aura-framework

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWBQT.png)

**PrescriptiveResolutionTool.cmp**

<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,lightning:isUrlAddressable" access="global" controller="nfm_PrescriptiveToolPricingCtrl">

```
<aura:attribute name="orderNumber" type="String" default="0"/> 
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
<aura:attribute name="orderPrescPriceLineItemList" type="List" Description="nfm_PrescriptiveToolPricingCtrl.PrescriptivePriceLineItemWrapperClass"/>
<lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace"/> 
<aura:attribute name="isLoading" type="Boolean" default="true"/>
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.isLoading}">
    <lightning:spinner alternativeText="Loading" size="medium" variant="brand"/>
</aura:if>
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.orderPrescPriceLineItemList.length > 0}">
<article class="slds-card">
                <div class="slds-card__header slds-grid">
            <!-- code to display card header -->
            <header class="slds-media slds-media_center slds-has-flexi-truncate">                    
                <div class="slds-media__figure">
                    <span class="slds-icon_container">
                        <lightning:icon style="background-color: rgba(32,178,170,1);" iconName="custom:custom29" size="small"/>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-media__body">
                    <h2 class="slds-card__header-title">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-card__header-link slds-truncate" title="Prescriptive Order Line Items">
                            <span>
                                Prescriptive Resolution Items   
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </h2>
                </div> 
            </header>                
        </div>
    <div class="slds-card__body slds-card__body_inner">
            <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--fixed-layout" style="padding-top:0.1rem" role="grid" id="summaryTable">
                <!-- CODE TO DISPLAY THE TABLE HEADER STARTS HERE -->
                <thead class="slds-table_bordered">
                    <tr class="slds-text-title--caps">                                                                    
                        <th scope="col">                        
                            <p class="slds-truncate" title="Order Line Items">Order Line Items </p>                                                                                                    
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col">                        
                            <p class="slds-truncate" title="Product Description">Product Description</p>                                                                            
                        </th>               
                        <th scope="col">                        
                            <p class="slds-truncate" title="Sales Price">Sales Price Per Item</p>                                                        
                        </th>                
                        <th scope="col">                        
                            <p class="slds-truncate" title="Order Status">Order Status</p>                                                        
                        </th>                
                        <th scope="col">                        
                            <p class="slds-truncate" title="C/A Amount">C/A Amount Per Item</p>                                                        
                        </th>            
                        <th scope="col">                        
                            <p class="slds-truncate" title="CDL Amount">CDL Amount Per Item</p>                                                        
                        </th>            
                        <th scope="col">                        
                            <p class="slds-truncate" title="Maximum Resolution Amount">Maximum Resolution Amount Per Item</p>                                                        
                        </th>
                        
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.orderPrescPriceLineItemList}" var="record">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="slds-cell-wrap"> 
                                {!record.OrderLineItems }
                            </td>
                            <td class="slds-cell-wrap"> 
                                {!record.ProductDescription}
                            </td>
                            <td class="slds-cell-wrap"> 
                                {!record.SalesPrice}
                            </td>
                            <td class="slds-cell-wrap"> 
                                {!record.OrderStatus}
                            </td>
                            <td class="slds-cell-wrap"> 
                                {!record.CAAmount}
                            </td>
                            <td class="slds-cell-wrap"> 
                                {!record.CDLAmount}
                            </td>
                            <td class="slds-cell-wrap"> 
                                {!record.MaximumResolutionAmount}
                            </td>                                
                        </tr>
                    </aura:iteration>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
</article>
<aura:set attribute="else">
            <div align="center">
                <hr></hr>
                No Records Found
            </div>
        </aura:set>
</aura:if>
```

</aura:component>

**nfm_PrescriptiveResolutionToolHelper.js**

({

```
getPrescriptivePriceLineItemsInfo : function(component, event, helper) {

    var orderNumber = component.get("v.orderNumber");

    console.log('OrderId to Apex call' + orderNumber);

    var action = component.get('c.getOrderPrescriptivePriceLineItems');

    action.setParams({

        orderId: component.get("v.orderNumber")

    });

    action.setCallback(this, function(response) { 

        component.set('v.isLoading',false);

        var state = response.getState();

        var dataRetrieved = response.getReturnValue();            

        if (state === "SUCCESS") {

            console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dataRetrieved)));

            //console.log('Response of Prescriptive Resolution for an OrderNumber--' + dataRetrieved);

            component.set('v.orderPrescPriceLineItemList', dataRetrieved);

            

        }else if (state === "ERROR") {

            var errors = response.getError();

            if (errors) {

                if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {

                    console.log("Error message: " +

                                errors[0].message);

                }

            } else {

                console.log("Unknown error");

            }

        } 

    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);

}
```

})

**nfm_PrescriptiveResolutionToolController.js**

({

```
 doInit : function(component, event, helper) {

    var orderId = component.get("v.orderNumber");

    var myPageRef = component.get("v.pageReference");  

    if(myPageRef!=null){

        orderId = myPageRef && myPageRef.state ? myPageRef.state.c__orderNumber :  component.get('v.recordId');

        console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myPageRef.state)));

        console.log(orderId);   

    }else{

        orderId = component.get('v.recordId');

    }

    

    if(orderId!=undefined && orderId!=null){

        component.set('v.orderNumber',orderId);

        window.setTimeout(

            $A.getCallback(function() {   

                helper.getPrescriptivePriceLineItemsInfo(component, event, helper);     

            }),3000

        );            

    }

}
```

})

public class nfm_PrescriptiveToolPricingCtrl {

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<PrescriptivePriceLineItemWrapperClass> getOrderPrescriptivePriceLineItems(String orderId) {
    System.debug('OrderNumber Apex:' + orderId);
    List<ResolutionItems__x> resolutionItemList = nfm_ExternalResolutionItemRequest.getByOrderNumber(orderId);
    List<PrescriptivePriceLineItemWrapperClass> lineItemWrapperList = new List<PrescriptivePriceLineItemWrapperClass>();
    For(ResolutionItems__x objOrderLineItems : resolutionItemList){
        lineItemWrapperList.add(createLineItemWrapperObject(objOrderLineItems));
    }
    UserActivityController.createRecord('Prescriptive Tool', 'Order', orderId);
    return lineItemWrapperList;
}
  
private static PrescriptivePriceLineItemWrapperClass createLineItemWrapperObject(ResolutionItems__x objOrderLineItems){
    PrescriptivePriceLineItemWrapperClass objOrderLineItemWrapper = new PrescriptivePriceLineItemWrapperClass();
    objOrderLineItemWrapper.OrderLineItems = objOrderLineItems.OrderLineItemNumber__c;
    objOrderLineItemWrapper.ProductDescription = objOrderLineItems.ProductDescription__c;
    objOrderLineItemWrapper.SalesPrice = '$' + string.ValueOf(objOrderLineItems.SalesPrice__c);
    objOrderLineItemWrapper.OrderStatus = objOrderLineItems.OrderStatus__c;
    objOrderLineItemWrapper.CAAmount = '$' + string.ValueOf(objOrderLineItems.CreditAdjustmentAmount__c);
    objOrderLineItemWrapper.CDLAmount = '$' + string.ValueOf(objOrderLineItems.CDLAmount__c);
    objOrderLineItemWrapper.MaximumResolutionAmount = '$' + string.ValueOf(objOrderLineItems.MaximumResolutionAmount__c);
    
    return objOrderLineItemWrapper;
}


public class PrescriptivePriceLineItemWrapperClass{
    @AuraEnabled public String OrderLineItems{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String ProductDescription{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String SalesPrice {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String OrderStatus {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String CAAmount {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String CDLAmount {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String MaximumResolutionAmount {get;set;}
}
```

}

Comment: Please put all errors and code in code blocks and not images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the class `nfm_PrescriptiveToolPricingCtrl` do you have a method with matching name, `getOrderPrescriptivePriceLineItems`? Is it marked public (or global), static and `@AuraEnabled`? Does current user have profile/permission sets where you granted right to run this class?

Are you sure there's no other JS method (in controller or helper) that would have same name, effectively [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the getOrderPrescriptivePriceLineItems?

**Edit**

I don't know man, "works for me". I changed your component's top line to `<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId`. I changed your class to this (next time try to put more effort into making [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), don't paste a code dumps as is).

```apex
public class nfm_PrescriptiveToolPricingCtrl {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<PrescriptivePriceLineItemWrapperClass> getOrderPrescriptivePriceLineItems(String orderId) {
        System.debug('OrderNumber Apex:' + orderId);
        List<PrescriptivePriceLineItemWrapperClass> lineItemWrapperList = new List<PrescriptivePriceLineItemWrapperClass>();
        for(Integer i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
            lineItemWrapperList.add(createLineItemWrapperObject(i, orderId));
        }
        return lineItemWrapperList;
    }
      
    private static PrescriptivePriceLineItemWrapperClass createLineItemWrapperObject(Integer i, String orderId){
        PrescriptivePriceLineItemWrapperClass objOrderLineItemWrapper = new PrescriptivePriceLineItemWrapperClass();
        objOrderLineItemWrapper.OrderLineItems = String.valueOf(i+1);
        objOrderLineItemWrapper.ProductDescription = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet';
        objOrderLineItemWrapper.SalesPrice = '$ 123';
        objOrderLineItemWrapper.OrderStatus = orderId;
        objOrderLineItemWrapper.CAAmount = '$ 1';
        objOrderLineItemWrapper.CDLAmount = '$ 2 ';
        objOrderLineItemWrapper.MaximumResolutionAmount = '$ 3';
        
        return objOrderLineItemWrapper;
    }
    
  
    public class PrescriptivePriceLineItemWrapperClass{
        @AuraEnabled public String OrderLineItems{get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled public String ProductDescription{get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled public String SalesPrice {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled public String OrderStatus {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled public String CAAmount {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled public String CDLAmount {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled public String MaximumResolutionAmount {get;set;}
    }
}
```

dropped it on account page and it works? Waits 3 seconds with a spinner and then [image]

You sure you saved it all OK, you sure apex class compiled ok? Which browser? Some security settings in the browser maybe?
Do you have unit test for this? external objects are pain but at least have you tried a snippet of "execute anonymous" running your method and you're sure it returns something in developer console? Does it work if you ditch the 3 seconds delay, maybe your browser's setTimeout doesn't pass context variables well?

Comment: HI eyescream , i have updated the post with Apex class. it does have same method name and public access. And user has the permission to run the class on profile level.Can u please help?Thanks

Comment: HI eyescrema, the error was resolved when i ditch 3 sec delay.But the root cause of the issues is that the exception or the component error we are looking at is not able to find OrderNumber.can you please help.Thanks

Comment: What exactly is wrong. You pass a null or empty string to apex? You don't pass anything at all? You pass value that should be valid, can see it in apex debug logs but the external object search returns 0 rows? Does your apex code work when you run it manually from developer console -> execute anonymous? You'll have to cut the problem up a bit

Comment: @eyescream , crossposted [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/385102/uncaught-error-in-a-getcallback-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading).